# Como automatizar merge no git / github com hook ou outra ferramenta?

Tags: git, github, automatização

Tenho um repositório no Github e criei para esse repositório uma página no Github. Com isso, sempre que faço alterações no branch `master`, preciso entrar no branch `gh-pages`, fazer um `git merge master` e enviar para o devido branch.

Tem como automatizar essa tarefa, para sempre que eu fizer um `git push origin master` já enviar todas alterações para o branch `gh-pages`?

Vamos lá, basicamente os passos que eu faço são:

```
git add . // para adicionar todos arquivos
git commit -m "traduzido tais arquivos"
git push origin master // sei que é bom fazer um pull antes
```

e quando eu fazer esse push dai rodar essa automação lá no Github, que deveria ser algo como:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git merge master
git push origin gh-pages
git checkout master
```

Não sei se tem como melhorar esses 4 passos acima, mas é isso que não gostaria de fazer toda vez que eu fizer um push.

Comment: Dúvida rápida - por que você quer fazer isso?

Comment: Para eu não ter que sempre que fizer uma alteração ter que fazer todo o processo, um  dia posso esquecer e quebrar a cabeça do pq uma alteração não esta aparecendo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Espelhando código do master usando Git Hooks**

Caso queira colocar no `hook` do `push`, renomeie o arquivo `pre-push.sample` para `pre-push` e cole o seguinte código:

```
echo $DEPLOYING
if [ -z "$DEPLOYING" ]; then
  echo 'Deploying site...'
  export DEPLOYING='yes'
  git checkout gh-pages
  git merge master
  git push origin gh-pages
  git checkout master
  unset -v DEPLOYING
  echo 'done!'
fi
exit 0
```

Comment: Oi Luiz, então, até entendi o que passou, mas isso tem como colocar direto em um hook para ser executado, podendo eu fazer apenas um push? Obrigado

Comment: @MarceloDiniz com certeza!

Comment: opa, que bom, e é isso que preciso. Saberia me dizer em qual hook seria e como ficaria esse arquivo, pois vi que tem vários né?!

Comment: no `pre-push`, vou testar aqui pra te dar a resposta exata.

Comment: @MarceloDiniz veja se essa solução serve.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43149/discussion-between-marcelo-diniz-and-luiz-carvalho).

Answer (score 0):

**Com Jekyll**

Caso você estivesse utilizando Jekyll poderia criar um script com o seguinte comando:

```
#!/bin/bash
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix _site master 2> /dev/null`:gh-pages --force
```

então basta executar o script, no meu caso

```
./deploy
```

Você ainda pode deixar ele ainda mais dinâmico caso queira, utilizando o seguinte [script](https://github.com/cobyism/dotfiles/blob/master/bin/git-gh-deploy):

```
if [ -z "$DEPLOYING" ]; then
  echo 'Deploying site...'
  export DEPLOYING='yes'
  git push origin `git subtree split --prefix _site master 2> /dev/null`:gh-pages --force
  unset -v DEPLOYING
  echo 'done!'
fi
exit 0
```

Bastando então passar o diretório como parâmetro:

```
deploy path/to/your/site
```

Ou informar quando for solicitado pelo script.

**Jekyll com Hook**

Caso queira colocar no `hook` do `push`, renomeie o arquivo `pre-push.sample` para `pre-push` e cole o seguinte código:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$DEPLOYING" ]; then
  echo 'Deploying site...'
  export DEPLOYING='yes'
  git push origin `git subtree split --prefix _site master 2> /dev/null`:gh-pages --force
  unset -v DEPLOYING
  echo 'done!'
fi
exit 0
```